# Avoiding Task Cancelled Exception in Azure DocumentDB in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task, azure-cosmosdb

We are running a web-application which has multiple threads accessing the Azure's DocumentDB API through a singleton class to read or write data to our Cosmos database. In this class, we initialize our DocumentClient in the static constructor. Throughout our program, multiple threads can access database, calling methods such as the following (assume Uri is a globally defined property):

```
    public static async Task SaveItem<T>(T item)
    {
        try
        {
            await Client.UpsertDocumentAsync(Uri, item);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { 
          // Some Basic Exception Handling.
        }
     }
```

Almost every method is async, and we are never calling .Wait or .Result on the callers of these methods. The problem is, after saving a large number of items from multiple threads, we will eventually get the following exception:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

What is particularly odd about this exception is that, once thrown for the first time, no database calls (reads or writes) will succeed, all throwing this same TaskCancelledException. The only remedy we've found is to restart the program.

The full stack trace printout when the exception is thrown is as follows:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.<>c__DisplayClass10.<<InvokeAsync>b__f>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__1b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__1b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.<InvokeAsync>d__1f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.<ProcessMessageAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<ReadAsync>d__30c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<ReadDocumentPrivateAsync>d__18d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__1b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__1b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at AutomatedRegressionTestSuite.Managers.DatabaseManager.<GetItemAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Administrator\Perforce\WinBuildServer\tools\Asriel\AutomatedRegressionTestSuite\Managers\DatabaseManager.cs:line 451
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at AutomatedRegressionTestSuite.Managers.DatabaseManager.<GetItemById>d__8`1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Administrator\Perforce\WinBuildServer\tools\Asriel\AutomatedRegressionTestSuite\Managers\DatabaseManager.cs:line 104
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

How can we prevent these task cancelled exceptions from occurring, or at least handle them in a way such that our entire database is still accessible after one is thrown?

Answer (score 2):

TaskCanceledException is coming from httpclient, which means its a http timeout exception. Please check the load on client and an abnormal short spike on load can cause this. Otherwise one alternative is to raise requestTimeout in ConnectionPolicy to give it more time.

Comment: Thank you for help. Unfortunately our requirements demanded an abnormal short spike followed by long periods of low throughput. I've found that raising the request timeout as well as the retry options alleviates the problem.

Comment: How does one increase the requestTimeout when working with an Azure DocumentClient?